# Access the value of Checkboxes from controller - DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkbox

I am trying to make the **user update the value of the check box from DB.**

The view lists all the available workers in DB.
but when i try to access the list of checkbox, the view passes wrong data
ex. there're only 3 checkbox, and it sends 5 items of true/false value.

I really appreciate any assistance.

View Sample Code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateWorkersForTask", "Tasks", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.isChecked)
              @Html.CheckBox("WorkersID", item.isChecked)

        </tr>
    }
```

**and the controler is**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateWorkersForTask(IEnumerable<bool> WorkersID, IEnumerable<string> hiddens)  { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by design `@Html.CheckBox` and `@Html.CheckBoxFor` render 2 inputs, a checkbox and a hidden input. If you inspect the html you will see something like

```
<input name="WorkersID" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="WorkersID" type="hidden" value="false">
```

The reason for this is that unchecked checkboxes do not post back. so the second input ensures a value is posted back.  In the case where the checkbox is checked the `DefaultModelBinder`reads the first value which is true and ignores the second value (because it has the same name).

In your case you are not binding to you model, instead you are just reading all inputs with the name `WorkersID`. If you have 3 items but 5 values are posted back, it would mean that you checked 2 of the boxes.

To correct this, modify your view and action method as follows (note your model needs to be IList so the `for` loop works, or alternatively you can use a custom `EditorTemplate`

View

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count i++)
{
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].WorkersID)
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
ActionResult UpdateWorkersForTask(IEnumerable<YourModelType> model)
{
  foreach(YourModelType item in model)
  {
    // do something with the value of item.WorkersID
```